# How Can I Set back to last activity in react-native for android?

Tags: react-native

How Can I Set back to last activity in react-native for android?

My thinking is:

1 set _navigate in index.android.js

```
// 设置回退的堆栈
var _navigator;
BackAndroid.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', function() {
    if (_navigator && _navigator.getCurrentRoutes().length > 1) {
        _navigator.pop();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
});
```

2 pass navigator in RouteMapping:

```
RouteMapper: function(route, navigationOperations, onComponentRef) {
        _navigator = navigationOperations;
        if (route.name === 'detail') {
            // 问题详情页
            return (
                <DetailScreen
                  navigator={navigationOperations}
                  question={route.question} />
            );
        } else if (route.name == 'front') {
            // 首页
            return(
              <FrontScreen
                navigator={navigationOperations}
                />
            );

        }
    },
```

3 set push in list view

```
gotoDetail: function(question: Object) {
    this.props.navigator.push({
        id: question.question_id,
        name: 'detail',
        question: question
    })
```

But It not work. When I click back button in Android, it jump out the app?

How Can I do that?

Or Anyone can give some example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the following code to <your project>/android/app/src/main/java/com/<your project>/MainActivity.java:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (mReactInstanceManager != null) {
        mReactInstanceManager.onBackPressed();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Projects created with React Native 0.12 will behave correctly.

For more infos see this issue on Github https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/3223.

Comment: A couple little gotchas I found: even if you update the npm version of react-native you will need to run init, or update your MainActivity by hand.  This will need to be deployed to the device, auto updates of JS won't pick this up.

Comment: I added this code and now my project wont run, am I supposed to run an npm command in the terminal after I add it?  thanks

Comment: @Stefan Klasen Hi, why I get "ReactInstanceManager has private access on ReactActivity" error when I add this code?

Comment: Where do you declare `mReactInstanceManager` ?